# How do I make removable media (USB) autostart Windows Explorer when inserted?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, removable-media, autostart

How do I make removable (USB) media autostart Windows Explorer when I plug in the device?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Please explain the down votes.

Comment: I'm fighting back against the downvotes, even upvoting other's answers over my own. I realize that OP didn't give any kind of research that he'd done and a quick search turned up some answers but it helps to know the name of what you seek. It doesn't look like English is their first language - sorry OP - and I see no harm in helping them out. Not every question has to be an expert-level issue.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to hardest:

- Hold `Shift` while inserting your device
- Confirm that Autorun is enabled in Control Panel for your media type
- `HKEY_USERS\<your_SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` should be default value of `0×00000091` (hex) or `145` (decimal).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, then you're talking about `Autoplay` and you can change the settings to take one of several actions. The instructions of how to do so can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-autoplay-settings):

1. Open AutoPlay by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type autoplay, and then click AutoPlay.
2. Do one of the following:

   - To turn AutoPlay on, select the Use AutoPlay for all media and devices check box.
   - To turn AutoPlay off, clear the Use AutoPlay for all media and devices check box.
3. Click Save.

For me, it auto-detected my OS and redirected me to my particular help section. I think you want the phrasing for the action you want will be "Open folder to view files using Windows Explorer"